# Is there any guarantee in Python that an object is a reference?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
a = { 'b': { 'c': 'hello' } }
c_reference = a['b']
c_reference['c'] = 'goodbye'
```

Is there any **guarantee** in Python that that will **always** be a reference and not a copy?

It would certainly simplify blocks of code like this:

```
self.metrics['farms'][fid]['user_sessions']['updated'] = True
self.metrics['farms'][fid]['user_sessions']['last_sample'] =  metric['last_sample'] 
self.metrics['farms'][fid]['user_sessions']['local'] =  metric['local']
```

if instead it could be:

```
metric_sample = self.metrics['farms'][fid]['user_sessions']
metric_sample['updated'] = True
... etc ...
```

Comment: *be a reference and not a copy* How do you mean?

Comment: You mean besides that this is how it's specified and implemented? What exactly are you asking for, the specification/documentation where this is described? Are you concerned Python may sometimes choose to create a copy and sometimes use a reference?

Comment: Why and how would the dictionary copy it? It makes no sense.

Comment: @PeterWood in C++, where the majority of my experience is, a copy would be created unless a reference was passed. Python seems to be the opposite, where a reference is passed, and a copy only created when asked for.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave The C++ `map` doesn't create a copy, it [returns by reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). It's only if you explicitly assign to a value rather than a reference that a copy is created.

Comment: @PeterWood and that makes absolute sense. However, the semantics for C++ are default copy constructor. I don't remember off the top of my head if std::map provides a default copy constructor, but objects assignment defaults to that unless overridden by, for instance, forbidding copy construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* no distinction between "original" objects (or copies thereof) and "references to" them. *Everything* you deal with in Python is a reference. Multiple references to the same underlying object all have equal status. This is analogous to the way "hard links" work on a file system, if you're familiar with that.

Therefore, if you mean "is there any guarantee..?" in the sense of "is there a post-hoc test I can do to verify...?" then there's no answer because the question is based on flawed assumptions. But what you *can* do is test whether two references refer to the same underlying object by asking whether one `is` the other:

```
 a = { 'foo': [1,2,3] }
 b = a['foo']
 c = a['foo']
 d = [1,2,3]

 b is a['foo']    # returns True - same object
 b is c           # returns True - same object
 b is d           # returns False - not the same object
 b == d           # returns True - different objects, same value
```

On the other hand, if you mean an *a-priori* guarantee of the way `a['b']` lookup works:  in your example, where `a` is a `dict`, `c_reference` is indeed guaranteed not to be a copy, simply because that's how the `dict` is designed to work. It's also the way square-bracket subscripting works in all standard Python containers I can think of. In general, to make *copies* of Python objects, you have to do extra work: either pass the result into a compatible constructor—in your case perhaps `dict()` because `a['b']` itself is also a `dict`—or use the `copy` module.

That's the general Pythonic way of doing things, and it's how builtin and standard Python objects work, but there's no *general* guarantee. If `a` were not a standard container, but rather an instance of some custom third-party class, there's nothing to stop the implementer of that class from implementing `__getitem__` such that `a['b']` returns a copy, or indeed returns any arbitrary thing.

Comment: Hmm. Although that is interesting, not sure if it's helpful. Does that mean there's a guarantee or not? I'm coming from a C++ background.

Comment: Sorry, slightly missed the point of your question I think. See edit.

Answer (score 4):

Simple assignment *never* copies an object in Python, it always just lets the variable on the left side refer to the same object as the right hand side. No objects actually change.

And an assignment to an indexed object like `c_reference['c'] = 'goodbye'` does neither, it *mutates* the object referred to by `c_reference`. That means that the object referred to be `c_refernce` is *changed* (*mutated* means the same). All variables referring to c_reference still do, so they all "see" the change.

For instance,

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a  # Now they both refer to the same list
>>> a[2] = 4  # Mutates (changes) the list
>>> b
[1, 2, 4]  # Changed
>>> a = [4, 5, 6]  # Assigns a new list to a
>>> b
[1, 2, 4]  # That didn't change what b refers to
```

Lists are mutable, so they can be changed. Tuples, strings, numbers aren't:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a[2] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Watch out, operators like `+=` are *surprising*, their effect depends on the mutability of the object:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a[2] += 1  # a is mutable, so this mutates
>>> b
[1, 2, 4]  # So they still refer to the same, now mutated item

>>> a = 3
>>> b = a
>>> a += 1  # A number isn't mutable, so this let's a refer to the _new object_ that is the result of 3 + 1
>>> b  # Still refers to the old one
3
```

The [language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) words it like this (leaving things out):

> Assignment of an object to a single target is recursively defined as follows: the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace.

So what I called a variable is called a *name*, and it is simply bound to the object. So that's the guarantee.

Forms like `c_reference[2]` fall under "the target is a subscription":

> If the target is a subscription: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield either a mutable sequence object (such as a list) or a mapping object (such as a dictionary). Next, the subscript expression is evaluated.
>
> If the primary is a mutable sequence object (such as a list), the subscript must yield a plain integer. If it is negative, the sequence’s length is added to it. The resulting value must be a nonnegative integer less than the sequence’s length, and the sequence is asked to assign the assigned object to its item with that index. If the index is out of range, IndexError is raised (assignment to a subscripted sequence cannot add new items to a list).
>
> If the primary is a mapping object (such as a dictionary), the subscript must have a type compatible with the mapping’s key type, and the mapping is then asked to create a key/datum pair which maps the subscript to the assigned object. This can either replace an existing key/value pair with the same key value, or insert a new key/value pair (if no key with the same value existed).

So "the mapping is asked to create a key/datum pair which maps the subscript to the assigned object". That means the mapping is mutated, the new pair is created in the mapping.

Note that I left a lot out details about other cases out.

Comment: I like the answer, but a simple explanation of what mutation is would be helpful, and also a confirmation (or not) of a guarantee like I asked. Will mark as answer correct if so.

Comment: I don't really care about being accepted or not and don't have time right now to look up the language reference or so. Did I manage to clear up something for you in the way assignment works?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did learn some, but not an answer to my question.

Comment: In 15 years as a programmer, I've understood mutability of an object, discussed it, etc., but never came across someone actually putting it into verb form to express changing a mutable object. That is where my confusion came in. A+ for the excellent answer - which came after I had already accepted another answer, and thank you for the learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All python objects are references. If you want to *copy* an object and get the reference to it, you can use `copy.copy()`:

```
import copy
copy.copy(obj)
```

or use `copy.deepcopy` to copy the object and all the objects it contains.

---

> the parameter passed in is actually a reference to an object (but the reference is passed by value)

Comment: I think you're confusing terminology. All Python names are references to objects.